# Android : Read ChekboxPreference value from Service

Tags: android, service, checkboxpreference

I have an Android `Service` which implements `SensorEventListener` for detecting motion. I've a `CheckBoxPreference` where user can choose to enable or disable motion detection. The problem I'm facing is that I'm not able to get the correct value in the service, namely in the `OnSensorChanged` method.

The service is started as soon as the application is launched. There is an activity which starts the service, and is binded with it.

Service where I detect the motion change:

```
    public class MotionService extends Service implements SensorEventListener{

     public static int SHAKE_THRESHOLD = 0;
    public static boolean SHAKE_ENABLE = false;
 @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        if (D) Log.d(TAG, "Creating service");
        super.onCreate();
 SHAKE_THRESHOLD = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext()).getInt("shake_threshold",60)*10;
        SHAKE_ENABLE = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext()).getBoolean("shake_enable",false);
}

    @Override
        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
            Sensor mySensor = event.sensor;

            if (mySensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
                float x = event.values[0];
                float y = event.values[1];
                float z = event.values[2];
                long curTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                if ((curTime - lastUpdate) > 100) {
                    long diffTime = (curTime - lastUpdate);
                    lastUpdate = curTime;

                    float speed = Math.abs(x + y + z - last_x - last_y - last_z)/ diffTime * 10000;

                    Log.d("Sensor Changed",SHAKE_THRESHOLD+"================="+SHAKE_ENABLE); //values here remain the same ones i assign on OnCreate, even though i change it in the settings. It should change when i change from settings. NOT HAPPENING!!

                        if (speed > SHAKE_THRESHOLD) {
                            //do sensor related stuffs here
                            if (SHAKE_ENABLE) { //the boolean value i get from the preferences

                                if ((x) > 8.0000) {
                                    Log.d("sensor", "=====LEFT====");

                                } else if ((x) < -8.0000) {
                                    Log.d("sensor", "=====RIGHT====");


                                } else if ((z) < -0.0) {
                                    Log.d("sensor", "=====UP====");

                                } else if ((y) < 1.0) {
                                    Log.d("sensor", "=====DOWN====");

                                }
                            }
                            last_x = x;
                            last_y = y;
                            last_z = z;
                        }
                }

            }

        }
    }
```

And this is my preference activity:

```
public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity {
@Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Fade it in
        overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);
final CheckBoxPreference checkboxPref = (CheckBoxPreference) getPreferenceManager().findPreference("shake_enable");

        checkboxPref.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
            public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
                Log.d("MyApp", "Pref " + preference.getKey() + " changed to " + newValue.toString());
                if (newValue.toString().equals("true")){
                    MotionService.SHAKE_ENABLE=true;
                    Log.d("SHAKE_ENABLE",MotionService.SHAKE_ENABLE+"================="+MotionService.SHAKE_THRESHOLD);
                    MotionService.SHAKE_THRESHOLD = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext()).getInt("shake_threshold",60);
                }
                else{
                    MotionService.SHAKE_ENABLE=false;
                    Log.d("SHAKE_ENABLE",MotionService.SHAKE_ENABLE+"================="+MotionService.SHAKE_THRESHOLD);
                    MotionService.SHAKE_THRESHOLD = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext()).getInt("shake_threshold",60);
                }
                    return true;
            }
        });
    }
```

So when I check and unchek, the logs from the `SettingsActivity` show that values of `MotionService.SHAKE_ENABLE` and `MotionService.SHAKE_THRESHOLD` are changed, but it is not reflected in the `OnSensorChanged` method of the `MotionService`.

Where am I going wrong? Help Appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Why you even bother checkbox? if this is your preference checkbox then each change is reflected in your app's preferences. So basically just read current state of your preference

Comment: I tried doing that in the OnSensorChanged method using getDefaultSharedPreferences(). Still the values won't change even after checking/un-checking the checkbox.